# Get the selected value in google app script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

How to pass a select box value.

I have a spreadsheet where i want to filter based on a select box value.

I made a way to call the app function on form submit. But I am not able to pass one more parameter at the other side.

I want to filter based on the select box value and thereby retrieve the result from the spreadsheet on to the web app. This is my selectbox in html.

```
 Select DATA   
 <select name ="productId" id="gettheVAL">
   <option>DATA1 </option>   
  <option>DATA2 </option>
 <option>DATA3 </option>
 </select>
```

Can anyone guide me on this? I have called the function via this

```
   form.on('submit', function(event){

        event.preventDefault();
        runner.withSuccessHandler(function(array){ 
             for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {

               var item = '<tr><td>' + array[i] +'</td></tr>';
                table.append(item);
        }

        }).retrieveValuesFromForm(this);
```

### Update

Adding the function - `retrieveValuesFromForm` below:

```
 function retrieveValuesFromForm(req) {

//var selectedvalue=$('input[name="gettheSelectValue"]:checked').val();// tried like this but $ is undefined here
var sheetActive = SpreadsheetApp.openById("SHEETID");
var sheet = sheetActive.getSheetByName("SHEETNAME");

var range = sheet.getRange('A:U'); 
var rawData = range.getValues();

var data = [];
for (var i = 0; i < rawData.length; i++) {
    if ((rawData[i][2] == selectedvalue)) // Check to see if column 3 says selectedvalue if not skip it
    {
        //processing
    }
}
return data;

}
```

Comment: Please add your GoogleAppsScript code for retrieveValuesFromForm() to your question.  That function could be written to take multiple parameters.

Comment: @terrywb Any idea how can i retrieve the  `<select name ="productId" id="gettheVAL">` data for the `selectedvalue`

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I pass a selected option and a few other things.

```
function sendText()
    {
      var culr=$('input[name="priority"]:checked').val();
      var type=$('#sel1').val();
      var txt=$('#txt1').val();
      var obj={'type':type,'text':txt,'color':culr};
      $('#txt1').css('background-color','#ffff00');
      google.script.run
        .withSuccessHandler(clearText)
        .dispText(obj);
    }
```

I'm guessing that you need to add this line into your head tag area.

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I have tried like this and i know its wrong.. can you help where iam wrong- **var selectedvalue=$('input[name="gettheSelectValue"]:checked').val();// tried like this but $ is undefined here**

Comment: I'm guessing that you need to add this to your head tag`<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>` I forget to do that all the time.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the assumption that you have a field in your form such as

```
<select name ="productId" id="gettheVAL">
```

In your form, You could call your Google App Script function with the following parameter

```
runner.withSuccessHandler(function(array){ 
    ...
}).retrieveValuesFromForm($("#gettheVAL").val());
```

You would then change the signature for retriveValuesFromForm

```
function retrieveValuesFromForm(selectVal) {
    ...
}
```